# Huge gap between JLabel and JRadiobutton?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jradiobutton

I have a problem. I have huge gap between the Label and radiobuttons but I dont want to have the gaps. I think it is because of my Layout but I am not sure.

**Importent: Below this is a Picture. Picture has more to say then words^^**

[image: Huge Gap and the Radiobutton is in the center bottom]

**"Action choose" is in the correct position. Now I just want to show the Radiobutton underneath of "Action choose". In the position of the 'c' of "Action choose". But this is not important.**

This is my Code how I create this type of styling. :)

```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel.add(new Label("Action choose:"));
JRadioButton action1 = new JRadioButton("Anime",false);
JRadioButton action2 = new JRadioButton("AMV",false);
JRadioButton action3 = new JRadioButton("OVA",false);
JRadioButton action4 = new JRadioButton("Manga",false);
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(action1);
    group.add(action2);
    group.add(action3);
    group.add(action4);

    panel.add(action1);
    panel.add(action2);
    panel.add(action3);
    panel.add(action4);
```

Best Regards

Kuku

Comment: The picture shows how it looks like, but not how it should be, and please, provide a valid [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see your issue

Comment: I am not so good in photoshop to show of but I descripe it in my post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
panel.add(new Label("Action choose:"));
```

Don't use a `Label`. That is an AWT component.

Use a `JLabel` for Swing a application.

A BoxLayout will respect the maximum size of a component. For a `JLabel` the maximum size is the same as the preferred size. For a `Label`, there is no maximum size so the label will take as much space as possible.

Comment: Ty, I hate it then this happen. Intelij generate me this :(